# PHP Display multiple files

Tags: php, file

I am wondering if there is an option (in PHP) to display a file. So for instance I want a file.php which displays text.pdf when I enter file.php?file=text.pdf . I had a little script for png. However I would like to use it for every file-format, so that it supports png equally as pdf. 
Is there a way to read a file and print it? It would really help in a file management system with limited user permissions

Comment: You want to be able to "display" the file or you want to be able to download it?

Comment: I just rethought my idea and downloading would be enough. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should be able to get any file downloaded.

```
$file = '/path/to/your/file.png';
$finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mime = $finfo->file($file);
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
echo file_get_contents($file);
```

Comment: Somehow this script only works for me when I replace 'sizeof()' with 'filesize()'. Why does this happen?

Comment: Your remark is absolutely right! You should be using `filesize($file)` instead, because `sizeof` is an alias to `count()`